# «if statement» for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, routes

I have nested routes in my `routes.rb`

```
resources :companies do
  resources :employees
  resources :accounts
end
```

In top menu I want to show a certain link when user is in company's controller or in nested controllers (employees, accounts). So, I want a simple  «if statement» for it.

I've tried several approaches.

```
<%= if params[:company_id].present? %> # doesn't work in company views
  # certain link
<% end %>

<%= if current_page?(controller: 'companies') %> # doesn't work in nested controllers' views
  # certain link
<% end %>
```

Of course, it is possible to use both of them with `or`, but I think it can be a better way for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use controller_name:

```
<% if controller_name.match(/^companies/) %>
    # certain link
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**
Alternatively, use controller_path:

```
<% if controller_path.match(/^companies/i) %> 
    # certain link
<% end %>
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work in nested views. For ex: `domain.com/companies/1/accounts/3`

Comment: @PeterTretyakov, can you check with my 2nd method? If it works for you, I'll erase the first one.