# Change Rails link paths for application behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a Rails application (http://example.org) where multiple tenants can have a simple CMS. They get a frontend which resides at `http://example.org/frontend/clients/:client_name` with relative sub-paths such as `/posts` and `/media`.

Now I wanted to allow tenants to use a custom domain, so the application will e.g. respond to a request to `http://example.com/posts` with the contents of `http://example.org/clients/example.com/posts`.

I managed to write an Nginx `proxy_pass` rule to get that working [see below]. The problem is now that the relative Rails link helpers which are served on `http://example.com/posts` (e.g. `frontend_client_media_path`) still point to the paths defined in Rails, e.g. `http://example.com/clients/example.com/media`.

Is there a possibility to tell Rails to construct the paths differently, by leaving out the `/clients/example.com` part, as long as the site is accessed by a custom domain?

**Appendix**

Nginx-Rule (the meat of it)

```
server {
  server_name _; # allow all domains

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://upstream/frontend/clients/$host$request_uri; # proxy to client-specific subfolder
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a conditional in the routing that checks for the host and then loads a custom path.

[Constraints based on domain/host Or Complex Parsing/Redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27220384/737275)

```
constraints(host: /^(?!.*example.org)/) do
    # Routing
end

# http://foo.tld?x=y redirects to http://bar.tld?x=y
constraints(:host => /foo.tld/) do
    match '/(*path)' => redirect { |params, req|
        query_params = req.params.except(:path)
        "http://bar.tld/#{params[:path]}#{query_params.keys.any? ? "?" + query_params.to_query : ""}"
    }, via: [:get, :post]
end
```

> Note: If you're dealing with full domains instead of just subdomains, use :domain instead of :host.

[You can also include other logic to fine tune it for ex:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835369/737275)

You could use controller_name or controller_path:

```
<% if controller_name.match(/^posts/) %>
    # Routing
<% end %>

<% if controller_path.match(/^posts/i) %> 
    # Routing
<% end %>
```